# Jquery fade and scale together

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, fade

I have this code: https://jsfiddle.net/og248ev0/

```
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="a"></div>
```

When top div fades out, second div jumps to its place above. (as expected)

How can I make it that **after** top div fades out, second div **animates** up, not just jumps?

Thanks

---

EDIT:

I have another version with text:

https://jsfiddle.net/og248ev0/7/

The problem here is that second item 'jumps' and animation end because of bottom margin.

Can I fix that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `animate()` separately for `opacity` and `height`. By default the animations are queued. So second will work after first.

```js
$('.a').eq(0)
  .animate({
    opacity: 0
  }, 1000)
  .animate({
      height: 0,
      marginBottom:0 //to get rid of the final jump because of margin
  }, 1000);
```

```css
.a {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="a"></div>
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/og248ev0/4/)

Comment: I wanted: after top div fades out, second div animates up.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I made another version with text, can you look at it?

Comment: @Toniq ok. You just need to add `marginBottom:0` in the second animation. like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/og248ev0/8/)

Comment: Even if  I add box-sizing: border-box;  it doesnt animate margin height to zero.. Isnt there a way to do this automatically? Otherwise I need to hardcode margin animation.